# Can't import sass file with webpack using ava

Tags: webpack, ava

I'm trying to test a React component with ava that also uses webpack. When I try to import styles from sass, the ava tests throw. How could I fix that?

`import './index.scss'`

```
SyntaxError: /src/index.scss: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .wrapper {
    | ^
  2 |   background-color: #fff;
  3 |   border-radius: 6px;
  4 |   padding: 4rem;
```

Comment: Saw the issue you opened on Github, upvoted even though someone else downvoted you :)